# SQL join over logical sequence

Tags: sql

I have two tables: ITEM (ID, GROUP) and STATE (ID, STATE)

[image: Tables]

What I need is a single SQL query that returns all items where within a group the state of the previous item changed from 'Done' to 'Open'. Previous item is defined as the item with highest smaller ID within same group.

In the example I would expect Id = 2 as result, because it is in group 'A' and the previous item with Id = 1 was in state 'Done'.

I have tried many ways but I am totally stuck...

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Why does your state table have more than 2 rows?

Comment: I use Oracle and the naming of the state table is not perfect, it should be ITEM_STATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `exists`.  This is almost a direct translation of your problem statement:

```
select i.*
from items i join
     state s
     on i.id = s.id
where s.state = 'OPEN' and
      exists (select 1
              from items i2 join
                   states s2
                   on i2.id = s2.id
              where s2.state = 'DONE' and i2.grp = i.grp and s2.id < s.id
             );
```

The only tricky part is the need for the `join`s to bring the tables together in both the outer query and subquery.